# Label on each bar ggplot in R

Tags: r, r-plotly, ggplotly

I'm plotting the age of the participants from a survey i've made. To plot this barchart I'm using this code:

```
plot_ly(y = dataIdade$total, x = dataIdade$Idade, name = "Idade", type = "bar")
```

But as you guys can see, the label of X is displaying only some numbers, I need to display all numbers on each drawed bar at least.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Tg2.png)

To tryout my code you can use this:

```
dataTeste=data.frame(
  individual=paste( seq(1,60), sep=""),
  value=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T)
)

plot_ly(y = dataTeste$value, x = dataTeste$individual, name = "Idade", type = "bar")
```

it's quite close

Comment: Can't see your bar chart, buddy. Also, please post some code that generates a small dataset with the same structure as the one one you're working with. Makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: sorry, had to do some urgent stuffs. updating the code..

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your plot's problem. But I have a feeling it's because it is taking your x-axis and making it continuous instead of discrete. Try converting  to a character vector? `dataTeste$individual <- as.character(dataTeste$individual)`

Comment: Oh god you are right. Thanks!!!

Comment: please put it as answer